# Regex to match words unless they have a character before them

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that detects hashtags. It shouldn't match things with letters before them, so we've got a space character at the beginning of the regex:

`/( #[a-zA-Z_]+)/gm`

The issue is it no longer matches words at the beginning of sentences. How can I modify this regex so that instead of matching with spaces, it simply DOESN'T match things with letters before them.

Thanks!

Comment: It would be real nice to see some examples of strings that should be matched and strings that should not. )

Comment: And please, people, don't just talk about some abstract `regex`. The regex will be used within some other tool, and what's the tool DOES matter.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize until an hour ago that regex was different in different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Use `\b` at the start to indicate a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).</del>
`\b` won't work, since `#` isn't a word starter.

Just check for the start of the string *or* a space before: `(?:^|\s)(\#[a-zA-Z_]+)`

Also, make sure you escape the `#`, so it doesn't get interpreted as a comment.

Comment: Like this? `/\b(#[a-zA-Z_]+)/gm`

Comment: Yes, that looks right.  I assume this is JavaScript flavored regex?

Comment: This: `$('body').text().match(/\b(#[a-zA-Z_]+)/gm)` won't match that.

Comment: Looks like a word boundary won't work, because `#` isn't considered a word character...

Answer (score 0):

Without **lookbehind**:

```
 pattern = /(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])#[a-zA-Z]+/​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

With **lookbehind** (but not allowed in **Javascript**):

```
 pattern = "(?:^|(?<![a-zA-Z]))#[a-zA-Z]+"
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have lookbehind.  You also need to double-escape when the pattern is in a string literal -- `\w` in a quoted string is the letter 'w'.